# Restart line numbers after every chapter

Tags: line-numbering, lineno

I am using the `lineno` package to add line numbers to my document. Is there a way to restart the numbering after every chapter?

There is an option called `pagewise` which restarts line numbering on every page. But I'm looking for something like "`chapterwise`" numbering.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `\resetlinenumber` before `\chapter`.

Automating it is maybe better:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\preto{\chapter}{\resetlinenumber}

\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Second}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]